# How to change `ionic serve` to use localhost instead of IP?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Run `ionic serve` shows the following message. However, I have a facebook login in azure and the CORS only accepts `localhost`. Is it a way to change the IP address to `localhost`?

```
Running live reload server: http://192.168.0.5:35729
Watching: www/**/*, !www/lib/**/*, !www/**/*.map
√ Running dev server:  http://192.168.0.5:8100
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ionic serve --address localhost` should work.

Comment: It should be noted that as soon as you use this, which works, live reload no longer works.